Stiefel C-manifold: volume and uniform distribution
I'm trying to define the uniform distribution on the Stiefel $C$-manifold (Downs 1972), given by $\mathcal{V}_{p,n}(C) = \{ X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times p} : X' X = C \}$ for $n \geq p$ and $C > 0$. Therefore I need to define a measure on $\mathcal{V}_{p,n}(C)$, and to normalize this measure I need an explicit expression for the volume of $\mathcal{V}_{p,n}(C)$.
Let $\mathcal{V}_{p,n} = \mathcal{V}_{p,n}(I_p)$.
It is well known that
$$
\tag{1}\label{1}
\text{Vol}(\mathcal{V}_{p,n}) 
= \int_{\mathcal{V}_{p,n}} (Q_1' dQ_1^\phantom{'})
= \prod_{i = 1}^p A_{n - i + 1}(1)
= \frac{2^p \pi^{np/2}}{\Gamma_p(n/2)},
$$
where $(Q_1' dQ_1^\phantom{'}) = \bigwedge_{i = 1}^p \bigwedge_{j = i + 1}^n \mathbf{q}_j' d\mathbf{q}_i$ with $[Q_1^{} : Q_2^{}] = [\mathbf{q}_1, \dots, \mathbf{q}_p : \mathbf{q}_{p + 1}, \dots, \mathbf{q}_n] \in O(n)$ denotes the differential form for the invariant Haar measure on $\mathcal{V}_{p,n}$, and
$$
A_m(r) 
= \frac{2 \pi^{m/2}}{\Gamma(m/2)} r^{m - 1}
$$
is the surface area of the $m$-dimensional sphere of radius $r$, see e.g. Chikuse (2003), Muirhead (2005) and DLMF (5.19.4).
For $C > 0$, I found the following related, but seemingly different, results:


Let $B$ be a constant nonsingular $p \times p$ matrix, and transform $Q_1 \to Q_1 B = X$.
Then 
$$
(X' dX) 
= (B'\ Q_1' dQ_1^\phantom{'}\ B) 
= (\det B)^{p - 1} (Q_1' dQ_1^\phantom{'}),
$$
since $Q_1' dQ_1^\phantom{'}$ is a skew-symmetric $p \times p$ matrix. Note that $B \in O(p)$ proves that the corresponding measure is right invariant. Taking $B = C^{1/2}$ yields
$$
\tag{2}\label{2}
\int_{X' X = C} (X' dX)
= (\det C)^{(p - 1)/2} \int_{\mathcal{V}_{p,n}} (Q_1' dQ_1^\phantom{'})
= \text{Vol}(\mathcal{V}_{p,n}) (\det C)^{(p - 1)/2}.
$$


Hsu (1940) proved the following theorem: 
let $X$ be an $n \times p$ matrix of rank $p \leq n$, and $f(\cdot)$ a function of $X$ which depends on $X$ through $X' X$ only. Then
$$
\tag{3}\label{3}
\int_{X' X = C} f(X' X) (dX)
= \frac{\pi^{np/2}}{\Gamma_p(n/2)} (\det C)^{(n - p - 1)/2} f(C).
$$


Waal (1983) states without proof the following expression for the surface area of the Stiefel $C$-manifold:
$$
\tag{4}\label{4}
\text{Vol}(\mathcal{V}_{p,n}(C)) 
= \int_{\mathcal{V}_{p,n}(C)} [dX]
= \text{Vol}(\mathcal{V}_{p,n}) (\det C)^{(n - p - 1)/2},
$$
where $[dX]$ denotes "the measure on $\mathcal{V}_{p,n}(C)$".


Cadet (1996), using slightly different notation, shows that the volume of the Stiefel $C$-manifold is given by
$$
\tag{5}\label{5}
\frac{\text{Vol}(\mathcal{V}_{p,n}(C))}{\text{Vol}(\mathcal{V}_{p,n})}
= \frac{1}{2^{p(p - 1)/4}} (\det C)^{(n - p)/2} \prod_{1 \leq i < j \leq p} \sqrt{\lambda_i + \lambda_j},
$$
where $\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_p$ are the eigenvalues of $C$.
This may be rewritten as
$$
\tag{6}\label{6}
\text{Vol}(\mathcal{V}_{p,n}(C)) 
= \prod_{i = 1}^p A_{n - i + 1}(\sqrt{\lambda_i}) \prod_{j = i}^p \sqrt{(1 + \lambda_j / \lambda_i)/2}.
$$


Since my knowledge of differential forms is limited, I have the following questions:


For $C = I_p$ the volume should be equal to \eqref{1}, and for $p = 1$ we expect $\text{Vol}(\mathcal{V}_{1,n}(c)) = A_n(\sqrt{c})$. Therefore \eqref{5} seems correct, while \eqref{2}, \eqref{3}, \eqref{4} do not calculate the volume of the Stiefel $C$-manifold. I'm having trouble to understand why this is not the case.


What is the (geometric) interpretation of the unitless scaling factors $\sqrt{(1 + \lambda_j / \lambda_i)/2}$ in \eqref{6}?


Given $(Q_1' dQ_1^\phantom{'})$, how can I obtain a (normalized) measure on $\mathcal{V}_{p,n}(C)$?
E.g. in the paper by Cadet, the Jacobian of $U \to U C^{1/2}$ (where $U \in \mathcal{V}_{p,n}$) is given by \eqref{5}, and a measure is constructed using "the riemannian volume on $\mathcal{V}_{p,n}(C)$ induced by the riemannian structure of $\mathbb{R}^{n \times p}$". I don't know how this relates to $(Q_1' dQ_1^\phantom{'})$ and the Jacobian in \eqref{2}.


Bibliography:
Cadet, A. (1996). “Polar Coordinates in ${\bf R}^{np}$; Application to the Computation of the Wishart and Beta Laws”. In: Sankhya: The Indian Journal of Statistics, Series A (1961-2002) 58 (1), pp. 101–114. ISSN: 0581572X. JSTOR: 25051086.
Chikuse, Y. (2003). Statistics on Special Manifolds. Lecture Notes in Statistics. Springer New York. ISBN: 978-0-387-21540-2. DOI: 10.1007/978-0-387-21540-2.
Downs, T. D. (1972). “Orientation Statistics”. In: Biometrika 59 (3), pp. 665–676. ISSN:
00063444, 14643510. JSTOR: 2334817.
Hsu, P. L. (1940). “An algebraic derivation of the distribution of rectangular coordinates”. In: Proceedings of the Edinburgh Mathematical Society 6 (3), 185–189. ISSN: 0013-0915, 1464-3839. DOI: 10.1017/S0013091500024731.
Muirhead, R. J. (2005). Aspects of Multivariate Statistical Theory. Wiley Series in Probability and Statistics. John Wiley and Sons. ISBN: 978-0-471-76985-9.
Waal, D. J. de (1983). “Quadratic Forms and Manifold Normal Distributions”. In: Contributions to Statistics: Essays in Honour of Norman L. Johnson. Ed. by P. K. Sen. North-Holland, pp. 115–121. ISBN: 0-444-86658-2.
